# How to do piecewise optimization if given model but not the fusage points?

Tags: optimization, soft-question, regression, mathematical-modeling, interpolation

Fitting data with piecewise models given fixed points of fusage, or intervals of validity with given number of continous moments across the models is a well explored problem with hundreds if not thousand of methods. But what if we don't know the points of fusage of the models? Can we find a method to adaptively find the points of fusage or intervals of validity for each model?

Here is example of a noisy function which we want to fit say two polynomials $p_1(x),p_2(x)$ to. How can we choose the fuseagepoint $x_0$ to get as good a fit as possible given we enforce $$p_1^{(k)}(x_0) = p_2^{(k)}(x_0), \forall k \in [0,n]$$

or a softer variant, penalty terms added to the piecewise fitter (assuming an optimization):

$$\sum_k\epsilon_k\|p_1^{(k)}(x_0) - p_2^{(k)}(x_0)\|_2^2$$

[image]

Comment: Something like that https://de.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/optknt.html?requestedDomain=true ?

Comment: @user251257 maybe, I have not checked it out yet.